# Can I find out the size of a shared OneDrive folder?

Tags: onedrive, shared-folders, size

I need to figure out the total size of a shared OneDrive folder. This folder can't synchronized with my local drive since it's huge and contains stuff like backup files from several people in our organization.

I can ask our admin for this info but can I do it myself?

Answer (score 0):

I use OneDrive via Microsoft 365 at home and only for myself. These steps worked for me.

1. log into cloud version : https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/signin/
2. In 'View Options' next to 'Sort' on top right,  select 'List' which will show you the size of the folder

Comment: Under "file size" it gives me the number of items in a folder not its size. Plus the item count is only for the next level down the folder tree not the whole tree.

Comment: It looks like there are different behaviors for a personal OneDrive which I'm using and a Business one which I believe you are using. I did a quick search and found this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/display-the-size-of-a-onedrive-folder-in-the/1397901f-2169-4f65-b505-08ed20247a65 stating this. There isn't a solution here though. Sorry I am unable to help. Hope you find the answer.